# Calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{N}z^n$ and show that if $z\not=1$ $|\sum_{n=1}^Nz^n |\leq \frac{2}{|1-z|}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|z|=1$. Calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{N}z^n$ and show that if $z\not=1$
$$|\sum_{n=1}^Nz^n |\leq \frac{2}{|1-z|}$$
and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$ converges.

This is what I tought:
$z=e^{\phi i}$, therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{N}z^n=e^{\phi i}+e^{2\phi i}+...+e^{N\phi i}$.
Intuitive I would say that some of those $z^n$'s will cancel each other out, because they are opposites. If the distance between $z$ and $1$ is very small, then it will take a long time before they will cancel each other out, therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{N}z^n$ can get large. But I don't know how I can show that this can get larger then $\frac{2}{|1-z|}$. Any hints ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First part of the problem
$$
S_N = \sum_{n = 1}^N z^n = z + z^2 + z^3 + \ldots z^N = \frac{z\left ( 1-z^N\right )}{1-z}
$$
So absolute value of $S_N$ is:
$$
\left |S_N \right | = \left | \frac {z \left ( 1-z^N\right )}{1-z}\right | = \frac {\left | z\right | \left | 1-z^N\right |}{\left | 1-z\right |} = \frac {\left | 1-z^N\right |}{\left | 1-z\right |} \leq \frac{\left | 1\right | + \left | z^N\right |}{\left | 1-z\right |} = \frac 2{\left | 1-z\right |}
$$

## Update

For the second part, I'd observe that
$$
\text{Log} \left ( \frac 1{1-z} \right ) = z + \frac {z^2}2 + \frac {z^3}3 + \ldots \frac {z^n}n + \ldots = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {z^n}n
$$

Comment: How do you get this result: $z + z^2 + z^3 + \ldots z^N = \frac{z\left ( 1-z^n\right )}{1-z}$ ? Should this last $n$ not be $N$ ?

Comment: It's simple geometric progression.

Comment: and yes, it should be $N$, of course.